# Outputting Opening Hours in SEOmatic

Tags: craft3, plugin-seomatic

I could use some help outputting opening hours from SEOmatic's Site Settings/Identity. The docs aren't clear on this, and the example at https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/issues/843 doesn't work for me. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up just repurposing code from the plugin templates. This is working fine for me:

```
{% if seomatic.site.identity.localBusinessOpeningHours|length %}
   {% macro day(value, day) %}
      <tr>
         <th>{{ craft.app.locale.getWeekDayName(day) }}</th>
         <td>{{ value[day].open.date|date('g:ia')|replace({':00' : ''}) }}-{{ value[day].close.date|date('g:ia')|replace({':00' : ''}) }}</td>
      </tr>
   {% endmacro %}
   {% from _self import day %}

   {% set startDay = currentUser.getPreference("weekStartDay") ?? craft.app.config.general.defaultWeekStartDay %}
   {% set days = (startDay..6) %}

   {% if startDay != 0 %}
      {% set days = days|merge(0..(startDay -1)) %}
   {% endif %}

   <table>
      {% for i in days %}
         {{ day(seomatic.site.identity.localBusinessOpeningHours, i) }}
      {% endfor %}
   </table>
{% endif %}
```